# Angular configuring components dynamically with angular routing is not working as expected

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a dynamic workflow using angular 5.

The app is a wizard with multiple steps, whose steps can be configured using json file for each client. e.g.
 
client 1 , will have step1, step2, step3, step4 

client 2 , will have step1, step3, step4

In my AppComponent's construtor, I have following code

```
constructor(private router: Router, private customServices: CustomServices) {

let injector = Injector.create([
  { provide: "page1", useClass: Page1Component, deps: [] },
  { provide: "page2", useClass: Page2Component, deps: [] },
  { provide: "page3", useClass: Page3Component, deps: [] },
  { provide: "page4", useClass: Page4Component, deps: [] }
]);

let comp1 = injector.get("page1");
console.log(comp1); // this works 

this.router.config.unshift(
  { path: 'page1', component: comp1 }, // this fails 
  { path: 'page2', component: injector.get("page2") },
  { path: 'page3', component: injector.get("page3") },
  { path: 'page4', component: injector.get("page4") }
);

this.links = this.customServices.items ;
```

}

When I create component & log it to console, it works properly, see the line with comments as "this works"

But When I use that with router config, i get runtime error that the component must be registered as "entryComponents" with @NgModule, which i already did.

I have created a public repo to demo the problem, as below

https://github.com/ganeshmgaikwad/AngularDynamicRouteProblem

Can someone help me fix this please ??

Answer (score 0):

Try and Change it to the following

```
  constructor(private router: Router, private customServices: CustomServices ) {
;



    let injector = Injector.create([
      { provide: "page1", useClass: Page1Component, deps: [] },
      { provide: "page2", useClass: Page2Component, deps: [] },
      { provide: "page3", useClass: Page3Component, deps: [] },
      { provide: "page4", useClass: Page4Component, deps: [] }
    ]);

    let comp1 = injector.get("page1").constructor;
    console.log(comp1); // this works 

    let myRoutes = [{ path: 'page1', component: injector.get("page1").constructor},
      { path: 'page2', component: injector.get("page2").constructor },
      { path: 'page3', component: injector.get("page3").constructor },
      { path: 'page4', component: injector.get("page4").constructor }];

    this.router.config.unshift(
      ...myRoutes
    );

    this.links = this.customServices.items ;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your app.module.ts

```
  entryComponents: [
     HomeComponent,
     NotFoundComponent,
     Page1Component,
     Page2Component,
     Page3Component,
     Page4Component
   ],
```

no need to define explicitly. refer Angular Doc:https://angular.io/guide/entry-components#the-entrycomponents-array